# What script type should be used for Webpack bundles?

Tags: javascript, webpack

When including a [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) bundle in an HTML file with a script tag, what type should be used, and why is that the case? Is it consider basic JavaScript or an ES module? I noticed that the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) treats them as basic JavaScript, and I would like to verify this is the case. I am using ES modules with import and export.

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: That depends on your webpack configuration. Are you building ES modules?

Comment: Yes, I am using ES modules with import and export. However, I was under the impression that these statements were replaced with Webpack's module encapsulation concept. Maybe that is the source of my confusion.

Comment: If the file you are including contains `import` and `export`, it's a module. If not, it's a script.

Comment: I certainly understand your point, thank you. However, the documentation linked above uses import, and yet the script tag does not specify it as a module. Maybe the documentation is incorrect or the question is irrelevant?
https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#creating-a-bundle